# Appium Inspector app launches and freezes on iOS

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios

I start the Appium Server through the GUI as such:

[image]

Then I set up the Inspector. This version has the bundleId and I have also used "app" and given it the full path to the .app file. I also tried entering the "eventloopIdleDelaySec" value and that didn't seem to generate any real kind of change:

[image]

When I start, the app launches and then hangs. Inspector throws an error about not being able to start a session:

[image]

The log for the whole process is:

```html
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.2
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: localhost
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on localhost:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"13.0","appium:deviceName":"iPad Pro","appium:newCommandTimeout":120,"appium:udid":"9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865","appium:printPageSourceOnFindFailure":true,"appium:launchTimeout":120000,"appium:showXcodeLog":true,"appium:eventloopIdleDelaySec":3,"appium:bundleId":"(removed for privacy)","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"13.0","appium:deviceName":"iPad Pro","appium:newCommandTimeout":120,"appium:udid":"9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865","appium:printPageSourceOnFindFailure":true,"appium:launchTimeout":120000,"appium:showXcodeLog":true,"appium:eventloopIdleDelaySec":3,"appium:bundleId":"(removed for privacy","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"13.0","appium:deviceName":"iPad Pro","appium:newCommandTimeout":120,"appium:udid":"9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865","appium:printPageSourceOnFindFailure":true,"appium:launchTimeout":120000,"appium:showXcodeLog":true,"appium:eventloopIdleDelaySec":3,"appium:bundleId":"(removed for privacy)","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"13.0","appium:deviceName":"iPad Pro","appium:newCommandTimeout":120,"appium:udid":"9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865","appium:printPageSourceOnFindFailure":true,"appium:launchTimeout":120000,"appium:showXcodeLog":true,"appium:eventloopIdleDelaySec":3,"appium:bundleId":"(removed for privacy)","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1649787312321 (12:15:12 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[Appium] Appium v1.22.2 creating new XCUITestDriver (v3.59.0) session
[Appium] Applying relaxed security to 'XCUITestDriver' as per server command line argument. All insecure features will be enabled unless explicitly disabled by --deny-insecure
[BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
[BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[BaseDriver]     "platformName": "iOS",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "13.0",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "iPad Pro",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:newCommandTimeout": 120,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:printPageSourceOnFindFailure": true,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:launchTimeout": 120000,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:showXcodeLog": true,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:eventloopIdleDelaySec": 3,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:bundleId": "(removed for privacy)",
[BaseDriver]     "appium:includeSafariInWebviews": true,
[BaseDriver]     "appium:connectHardwareKeyboard": true
[BaseDriver]   },
[BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[BaseDriver]     {}
[BaseDriver]   ]
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   launchTimeout
[BaseDriver]   eventloopIdleDelaySec
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 040d4862-29e3-461a-a066-e50bfbc89889
[XCUITest] Current user: 'AJJohnson'
[XCUITest] Available devices: 
[XCUITest] No real device with udid '9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865'. Looking for simulator
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 13.1 with udid '9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865'
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865', real device: false
[BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1649787313084 (12:15:13 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1649787313085 (12:15:13 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1649787313085 (12:15:13 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[simctl] Error running 'terminate': An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Application termination failed.
FBSSystemService reported failure without an error, possibly because the app is not currently running.
[XCUITest] Reset: failed to terminate Simulator application with id "(removed for privacy)"
[simctl] Error running 'terminate': An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Application termination failed.
FBSSystemService reported failure without an error, possibly because the app is not currently running.
[iOSSim] Cleaning app data files for '', '(removed for privacy)'
[iOSSim] Checking whether simulator has been run before: yes
[iOSSim] Building bundle path map
[iOSSim] Could not find app directories to delete. It is probably not installed
[BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1649787314090 (12:15:14 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA path: '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent'
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA agent: '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[IOSSimulatorLog] Starting log capture for iOS Simulator with udid '9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865' using simctl
[BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1649787314789 (12:15:14 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Setting up simulator
[XCUITest] No reason to set locale
[XCUITest] No iOS / app preferences to set
[XCUITest] Setting did not need to be updated
[iOSSim] Setting preferences of 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865 Simulator to {"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}
[iOSSim] Setting common Simulator preferences to {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"PasteboardAutomaticSync":false}
[iOSSim] Updated 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865 Simulator preferences at '/Users/AJJohnson/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' with {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"PasteboardAutomaticSync":false,"DevicePreferences":{"9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865":{"SimulatorExternalDisplay":2114,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"ChromeTint":"","SimulatorWindowGeometry":{"C700E1E4-35C1-46C6-85E4-FB645071C7F3":{"WindowCenter":"{3100, 740.5}","WindowScale":0.8516260162601627}},"SimulatorWindowOrientation":"Portrait","SimulatorWindowRotationAngle":0}}}
[iOSSim] Got Simulator UI client PID: 74608
[iOSSim] Both Simulator with UDID '9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865' and the UI client are currently running
[BaseDriver] Event 'simStarted' logged at 1649787315772 (12:15:15 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou/Build/Products'
[WebDriverAgent] Got derived data root: '/Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou'
[WebDriverAgent] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[DevCon Factory] Requesting connection for device 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865 on local port 8100
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[DevCon Factory] Successfully requested the connection for 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865:8100
[XCUITest] Starting WebDriverAgent initialization with the synchronization key 'XCUITestDriver'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Error: timeout of 3000ms exceeded
[WD Proxy]     at createError (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
[WD Proxy]     at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:280:16)
[WD Proxy]     at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
[WD Proxy]     at Timeout._onTimeout (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:12)
[WD Proxy]     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
[WD Proxy]     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
[WebDriverAgent] WDA is not listening at 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/'
[WebDriverAgent] WDA is currently not running. There is nothing to cache
[XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 2 times with 10000ms interval
[XCUITest] These values can be customized by changing wdaStartupRetries/wdaStartupRetryInterval capabilities
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1649787319202 (12:15:19 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[WebDriverAgent] WebDriverAgent does not need a cleanup. The sources are up to date (1644399105000 >= 1644399105000)
[WebDriverAgent] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865, 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865.*XCTRunner, xctest.*9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865' for the device 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865...
[WebDriverAgent] 'pgrep -if 9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865.*XCTRunner' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[WebDriverAgent] 'pgrep -if xctest.*9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[WebDriverAgent] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -derivedDataPath /Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou -destination id=9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865 IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' in directory '/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent'
[WebDriverAgent] Output from xcodebuild will be logged. To change this, use 'showXcodeLog' desired capability
[Xcode] Command line invocation:
[Xcode]     
[WebDriverAgent] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[Xcode] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project "/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj" -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -derivedDataPath /Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou -destination id=9425DAD1-0C9D-443C-A084-19D07E5F2865 IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] User defaults from command line:
[Xcode]     IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou
[Xcode]     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Build settings from command line:
[Xcode]     COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
[Xcode]     GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS = 0
[Xcode]     IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.0
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[Xcode] note: Using new build system
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] note: Planning
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Analyze workspace
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Create build description
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Build description signature: d6de8fd937748038c806b37526b54212
[Xcode] Build description path: /Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/d6de8fd937748038c806b37526b54212-desc.xcbuild
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] note: Build preparation complete
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] note: Building targets in parallel
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] ** TEST BUILD SUCCEEDED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
[Xcode] 2022-04-12 12:16:13.603862-0600 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[75378:5071320] Running tests...
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] objc[75378]: Class LRUCache is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (0x113fbfa00) and /Users/AJJohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WebDriverAgentLib.framework/WebDriverAgentLib (0x12f429e78). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2022-04-12 12:16:13.854
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' started at 2022-04-12 12:16:13.856
[Xcode] Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' started at 2022-04-12 12:16:13.857
[Xcode]     t =      nans Suite Set Up
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Case '-[UITestingUITests testRunner]' started.
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.00s Start Test at 2022-04-12 12:16:13.897
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.00s Set Up
[Xcode] 2022-04-12 12:16:13.900733-0600 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[75378:5071320] Built at Apr 11 2022 12:51:13
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-04-12 12:16:13.915679-0600 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[75378:5071320] ServerURLHere->http://192.168.0.120:8100<-ServerURLHere
[Xcode] 2022-04-12 12:16:13.916411-0600 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[75378:5071364] Using singleton test manager
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"message":"WebDriverAgent is ready to accept commands","state":"success","os":{"testmanagerdVersion":28,"name":"iOS","sdkVersion":"15.0","version":"13.0"},"ios":{"simulatorVersion":"13.0","ip":"192.168.0.120"},"ready":true,"build":{"upgradedAt":"1644399105000","time":"Apr 11 2022 12:51:14","productBundleIdentifier":"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"}},"sessionId":null}
[WebDriverAgent] WebDriverAgent information:
[WebDriverAgent] {
[WebDriverAgent]   "message": "WebDriverAgent is ready to accept commands",
[WebDriverAgent]   "state": "success",
[WebDriverAgent]   "os": {
[WebDriverAgent]     "testmanagerdVersion": 28,
[WebDriverAgent]     "name": "iOS",
[WebDriverAgent]     "sdkVersion": "15.0",
[WebDriverAgent]     "version": "13.0"
[WebDriverAgent]   },
[WebDriverAgent]   "ios": {
[WebDriverAgent]     "simulatorVersion": "13.0",
[WebDriverAgent]     "ip": "192.168.0.120"
[WebDriverAgent]   },
[WebDriverAgent]   "ready": true,
[WebDriverAgent]   "build": {
[WebDriverAgent]     "upgradedAt": "1644399105000",
[WebDriverAgent]     "time": "Apr 11 2022 12:51:14",
[WebDriverAgent]     "productBundleIdentifier": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"
[WebDriverAgent]   }
[WebDriverAgent] }
[WebDriverAgent] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 54049ms
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1649787374577 (12:16:14 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"(removed for privacy)","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[Xcode]     t =     0.71s Open (removed for privacy)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.71s     Launch (removed for privacy)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.78s         Wait for accessibility to load
[Xcode]     t =     0.79s         Setting up automation session
[Xcode] 
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[Xcode] 2022-04-12 12:17:14.858130-0600 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[75378:5071320] Enqueue Failure: Failed to get automation session for (removed for privacy):75386: Timed out while requesting automation session for (removed for privacy) (pid:75386). /Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgentRunner/UITestingUITests.m 44 1
```

I am completely out of ideas and will happily take any advice.

EDIT: Forgot to add that this app works on the Xcode simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .ipa file in real device and .app will work only in simulators.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).